# IBM MobileFirst Push Notification in IPhone - when the app is closed, pushNotificationReceived method is not triggering for the received notification

Tags: iphone, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an application for IPhone, where I have to store all the notifications coming to the app using JSON Store.

In IBM Mobilefirst Push Notifications API, **pushNotificationReceived** is triggered when any notification is received in the app. So using this method, I can able to store the notifications in JSON Store.

When the app is closed [Not running in the background], the notification is successfully sent to the device.

But when I open the application by clicking the received notification, **pushNotificationReceived** method is triggering only for the notifications received when the app is closed.

Is this the default behavior of IBM MobileFirst?

If so, is there any work around to solve this issue.

I have seen that there are native API's available for handling the received notifications. Is that the only way to solve this?

Or Is there any native listener available only for receiving the notifications when the app is closed?

Comment: Are you clicking the notification in the notification center, or on the app icon in the home screen?

Answer (score 0):

1. If tapping the notification in the Notification Center, the `pushNotificationReceived` should be called.
2. If tapping the app icon after a notification was received, the `pushNotificationReceived` API will **not** be called.

This is the expected behavior in iOS.

If (1) is not working for you as well, I suggest that you will test the sample Hybrid app to see  whether it works for fails for you there as well - it should work: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/event-source-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/

Comment: I have tested the Sample Hybrid App in case 1 also the pushNotificationReceived is not getting called.

Comment: Tapping the notification in notification center will launch the application and thereafter the callback will execute. Please try with the sample Idan has provided.